# Magento 2 How to get "custom_atribute" Value in product page when atribute color drop down changes?

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes, magento-2.1.7

I need some suggestion or advise on how to get a custom attribute on product page.

I have my custom attribute code as **"is_featured**" it's a `Yes/No` value.

In product page when the user changes the colour drop down I need to check that simple product's **"is_featured"** value.

How could I achieve that any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have found a solution by just playing with it and found out a very easy solution:

```
$product = $block->getAllowProducts();

foreach ($product  as $child) {
  print_r($child->getIsFeature());
}
```